# How can I open .sketch files in Linux or Windows?

Tags: android, linux, windows, macos, sketch-3

I've an Android sketch template as a `.sketch` file. Unfortunately I can't use it on Linux or Windows, but the Sketch program is only for Mac OS. How can I open `.sketch` files in Linux or Windows?

Answer (score 11):

Windows: [Figma](https://www.figma.com) runs on Windows and opens `.sketch` files.

Linux: there's [Figma Linux](https://github.com/ChugunovRoman/figma-linux), an unofficial fork for Linux.

[image]

Comment: https://www.figma.com/downloads/ doesn't officially support linux as of now, though there is an unofficial varient: https://github.com/ChugunovRoman/figma-linux

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[FramerJS](http://framerjs.com/)** to parse sketch files. Its an online platform to export the html and css from the sketch files. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The [Lunacy](https://icons8.com.br/lunacy) app is focused on Sketch Files on Windows.

Answer (score -1):

[Avocode](https://avocode.com/open-sketch-on-linux) seems to be a pretty good alternative. They also have a free version that you can try it out before you decide to buy.

Comment: requires to set-up an account, can't open file without providing e-mail

Comment: Figma and Lunacy is the best way